# Coloring javascript local variables and parameters inside function bodies in aptana 3 on eclipse? Possible?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana3

I am aware that syntax coloring for aptana3 on eclipse is controllable from Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes ; however in that dialog I find no options to control the color of local JavaScript variable identifiers. I did find an option to color function parameters but it only colors them in the declaration part of functions and not in their bodies.

I am also aware that you can place your cursor on an item and click on Commands->Bundle Development->Show Scope to get something called a Scope Selector which can be used to create new items to color in the Themes dialog. Unfortunately that procedure returns nothing for variable and parameter identifiers inside function bodies.

Does anybody know whether this kind of coloring is supported by aptana3? Ideally I would like to color variables and parameters differently from each other, but I'll take uniform coloring of all identifiers if nothing else is available.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.